# Add copy of Existing Package using File System

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, copy, package

I'm copying packages from one server to another. When the package is of the type Integration Services Package it's easy to move but when it is T-SQL, I don't know how to move it.

I've moved all packages of the type Integration Services Package now, I'm left with the T-SQL type.

I'm not using a code based method, I'm using the SSIS interface to move the packages over.

I have 15 jobs that use T-SQL within them and no packages. I want to move them all over.

Comment: Do you mean that you have SQL Agent jobs that you want to migrate that are executing code in the job steps rather than executing packages?

Answer (score 1):

### Transfer Job Task

You can use Transfer Job Task to copy SQL agent Job from a server to another one

> The Transfer Jobs task transfers one or more SQL Server Agent jobs between instances of SQL Server.
>
> The Transfer Jobs task can be configured to transfer all jobs, or only specified jobs. You can also indicate whether the transferred jobs are enabled at the destination.

- [Transfer Jobs Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-jobs-task?view=sql-server-2017)

There are plenty of articles found online, as example:

- [Transfer SQL Server Jobs Task and Transfer SQL Server Logins Task in SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2081/transfer-sql-server-jobs-task-and-transfer-sql-server-logins-task-in-ssis/)

### Generate Scripts via SSMS

You can simply generate SQL scripts and execute them on the other server:

- [How can I move SQL Server Agent Jobs to different systems?](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/how-can-i-move-sql-server-agent-jobs-different-systems)